# System boot problem on upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, reboot, systemd

I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my Dell Latitude E5440 which I upgraded to 15.04 through the usual regular system updates that keep popping up from time to time. After the update process, system was supposed to reboot on its own. I kept waiting for the automatic reboot for quite long until I lost my patience and tried shutting down the system from the systems menu, to which nothing happened. I tried the system restart as well, and from the terminal as well but nothing happened. Finally I forced the power shut down. Now when I tried to switch it on, it won't boot. After several tries and a bit of research I found the way to boot it, but the system is now very very very slow to work on, despite the 8GB RAM. The way it reboots now is also very typical. When I switches it on, it won't boot and a purple screen persists forever. I have to force the power shut down and then switch it back again post which the advanced reboot menu appears. I've to select the (systemd) option, (upstart) and (recovery mode) won't work. Attached is the screenshot of the same. Post this an error screen appears related to ACPI and controller version, and then the OS loading screen.
[image]
Now, I've three questions before I loose my patience and re-format the system.

1. How can I make the system boot default in systemd mode. Evertime I want to use my system I've to switch it on, then force shut down, then start again and select the systemd option.
2. Secondly, why is everything behaving so slow. Is there any way I can boost the things?
3. Thirdly, can I downgrade back to 14.04 without loosing any data?

Comment: "systemd" is right there, seriously just select one of the systemd options (it 's the same anyway, it also repeats for me, on yours it actually repeats a bunch more.)

Comment: didn't get that. I can see the systemd there, what i am asking it i've to select it everytime, can i make it as default boot option.

Comment: Copy the code from the systemd boot and remove the original code of the normal boot and replace it with the systemd code

Comment: Do *NOT* manually modify the grub boot code; that code is automatically generated whenever kernel packages are updated, and you will lose those changed. (Worst case is that your system will no longer boot.)

Answer (score 0):

To make the systemd boot be the default, check to see if you have installed the `systemd-sysv` package (`apt-cache policy systemd-sysv`). If not, then go ahead and install it; it will likely ask if you want to remove `upstart-sysv`, and this is fine. If it is already installed, then reinstall it (`sudo apt-get reinstall systemd-sysv`).